# TLS Security Error on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: php, ssl, internet-explorer, tls1.2, vs-web-site-project

My website shows 'uses outdated or unsafe TLS security' error on Internet Explorer.
I know it is due to TLS Setting but is there any ways the site could be opened on IE browsers that are not configured manually for TLS settings?
I mean is there any ways to enable it by code?

Thanks.

Comment: If it is your site that is refusing to be connected to by IE which cannot use the minimum version of TLS your site requires, the only option would be to change your site (apache) to allow a less strong version of TLS to be used. That does not sound like a good idea

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that any code of the web application can change the security settings of the browser. So it is not possible to achieve your requirement using code.

You may need to modify your web app or settings on IE browser to access the site in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Is there any other way to show my website on IE? I mean that some users don't know how to change setting on IE, in this case how they can see the website. What about disabling TLS1.1 in Apache Server?

Comment: You can try to configure your site which can easily run in IE without changing the settings. I am not familiar with Apache server so I can't provide suggestions for it.